# A few triangle questions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Here are a few questions that I thought of while teaching high-school mathletes, which I thought were perhaps appropriate as training problems but then found them too hard. My geometry is also quite dusty.

Question 1: Let $T$ be an equilateral triangle in the plane, with unit area, with vertices $A_1, A_2, A_3$ say. Let $T_i$ be a triangle of unit area whose centroid is equal to $A_i$. What is the maximum possible value of the area of the region $T_1 \cap T_2 \cap T_3$, and what configuration of the $T_i$'s achieves this maximum?

Question 2: Same question as Question 1, except $T$ is now an arbitrary (non-degenerate) triangle of unit area.

(Cross posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406508/maximizing-the-area-of-a-region-involving-triangles))

Comment: No idea about Q1 (it looks hard). Q2 is trivial. The answer is same as Q1. This is because affine transform preserves the vertices-centroid relationships and ratio of areas of geometric figures.

Comment: I believe you can use symmetry in Q1 and start from trying to find symmetrical solution. Let $A$ is centroid of $T$. Consider isosceles triangle $T_1=A_{11}A_{12}A_{13}$, such that $\vec{AA_{11}}=k\vec{AA_1}$, $A_{11}A_{12}=A_{11}A_{13}$, $\vec{A_1A_{11}}+\vec{A_1A_{12}}+\vec{A_{1}A_{13}}=0$. This triangle is defined by number $k$. $T_2$ and $T_3$ are obtained from $T_1$ by rotation around $A$ by angles 120° and 240°. Then you can express area $T_1\cap T_2\cap T_3$ in terms of $k$ and find optimum $k$. It does not guarantee global optimum but it can be good place to start.